# Can we use lambda expression inside an interface as a default or static implementation inside interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, functional-programming, abstract, functional-interface

I have this strange doubt now, As far as I know, in order to use lambda expressions it should be a functional interface having single abstract method. Now the question is can we provide its implementation in another interface as a static or default implementations? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give a code example? A lambda expression is an instance of an interface. It's an object. It's not a method.

Comment: And my question is: "could you clarify your question, that is quite hard to understand, by posting a code example of what you would like to do?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a lambda expression that would represent an `A` instance regardless of the context you are in. It can be a static interface method, it could be a default interface method.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface A {
    void printMessage();
}
interface B {
    default void printMessage() {
        A a = () -> System.out.println("A implementation (1)");
        a.printMessage();
    }
}
interface C {
    static void printMessage() {
        A a = () -> System.out.println("A implementation (2)");
        a.printMessage();
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, it's not particularly useful because both methods could be simply rewritten to

```
System.out.println("...");
```

If there is a relationship between interfaces, a default method would provide an implementation for the method defined in the super interface. A static method would cause a compilation error since they can't override instance methods.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface A {
    void printMessage();
}
interface B extends A {
    @Override
    default void printMessage() {
        A a = () -> System.out.println("A implementation (1)");
        a.printMessage();
    }
}
interface C extends A {
    // compilation error
    static void printMessage() {
        A a = () -> System.out.println("A implementation (2)");
        a.printMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: @maddinaprudhviram I am glad it helped. Next time, please consider including code snippets to make your questions more clear. It would make answers precise and to the point.